# Upload file using selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium

I am using selenium vba and on the webpage there is an element that is supposed to enable me to upload a file. Here's the html for that element

```
<input type="file" name="attachments" id="attachments" accept=".pdf" maxlength="20" class="inputTextBox2">
```

I tried both methods to click on the element but the element doesn't respond at all

```
bot.FindElementById("attachments").Click
```

and

```
bot.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].click();", .FindElementById("attachments")
```

but both methods don't work and the element doesn't respond

Answer (score 0):

Solved as I discovered that the input is a textbox so I used SendKeys to send the path

```
.FindElementByCss(".inputTextBox2").SendKeys THEFILEPATH
```